# How do I display the name from one sql table linked by an id?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, linq

bit of a newbie to mvc. i am having trouble with the following scenario:

I have a view with the following:

```
        <tr>
        <% foreach (var game in (IEnumerable<Game>)ViewData["Game"])
           { %>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="selectedObjects" value="<%=game.Id%>" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <%=game.GMTDateTime%>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%=game.HomeTeamId%>                            
        </td>
        <td>
            <%=game.AwayTeamId%>
        </td>
        <td>
            <%=game.Venue%>
        </td>
        </tr>
```

All of the data displays OK except for HomeId and AwayId. These two fields are linked to another table called team and each Id in HomeTeamId and AwayTeamId relate to a record in the Team table and each id has a "Name". My problem is how do I display the "Name" from the Team table rather than the Id field shown.

The controller shows:

```
   ViewData["Game"] = dc.Games.GetGames();
```

The query I am using in linq is:

```
    public static IEnumerable<Game> GetGames(this Table<Game> source)
    {
        return from c in source
               orderby c.GMTDateTime
               select c;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have defined the relationships in your schema, this should work:

```
    <td>
        <%=game.Team.Name%>                            
    </td>
    <td>
        <%=game.Team1.Name%>
    </td>
```

Because there are multiple FKs to the Team table, you will see two properties for Team, `Team` and `Team1` (or similar). You'll need to determine which is which by looking at the generated LINQ code, or by trial and error, i.e., observing the output.

Normally using partial classes I will make additional properties that expose the Team object(s) with better names that make it clear which FK they are for.

Comment: crap! thanks very much that worked. i have been looking at this for hours. i was looking for a complicated solution...